# ASP.Net MVC No routes but default are working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have added a new Controller to my application, and then from there added in a new View (right click, add view on the context menu)

I have added the route to the Route table, but when I browse to it I get a `404`.

I can only assue that this is something fundamental that is wrong, as if I replace the values in the default route, I still cannot access my page.

The route table is;

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    "Classroom",
    "{controller}/{action}/",
    new { controller = "Classroom", action = "Index" }
);


routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    //defaults: new { controller = "Classroom", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

there is only a return `View()`; in the index method. I have installed Glimpse, but as I am getting a 404, I cannot actually see the url that is being passed back.

So, what techniques / tricks are there I can use to track this down, (and any common gotcha's that could be causing this?)

Visual Studio 2012, using the inbuilt webserver.

This is Fixed. It was a stupid Gotcha on my part. The Controller was Called Classroom not ClassroomController

Answer (score 2):

> I have added the route to the Route table

No, you don't need to add any route for that. Get rid of the `Classroom` route from your `Global.asax` and leave only the `Default` one. Now you could safely navigate to your controller using `/classroom/index` which will render the `Index` action of the `ClassroomController`.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help, I am still getting the 404. I have found the IISExpress log files, but all I have there is an error in EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER (404) not found, so I am struggling to understand why..